# I wrote a new paper. Should I reapply for a postdoc at mathjobs?

Tags: job-search, postdocs, mathematics

About a month ago, when the deadlines for applying for postdoc positions at math at the US were approaching, I applied for several research universities via mathjobs.

In the time that passed since, I made a new discovery, and am now in the last stages of writing a paper about it.

Obviously, once the paper will be uploaded to the arXiv, my application will be improved.

However, for that to happen, I must update my c.v and my publication list, to include the new paper.

To do this in mathjobs, I will need to "reapply". Given that deadlines passed, will this be a good idea? Can reapplying now with my new c.v and my new publication list harm my application because of deadline issues?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As I understand it, "reapply" is merely a technical term in mathjobs and this should cause no problems.  See, for example, the statement "Update (re-apply) applications as many times as you like, or whenever you have new info to add" in [MathJobs Workflow & Features](http://www.mathjobs.org/help/mathjobs/misc/flow.html).  I don't know why mathjobs uses the term "reapply," which certainly has the potential to cause confusion.  I can't guarantee that nobody will hold it against you, but I'd be very surprised if anyone did (and I think it would be a big mistake on their part).

Updating your application may not be enough if it has already been read.  I'd recommend also e-mailing key people you would like to work with to let them know about your new paper once it is on the arXiv.  Of course you shouldn't spam large numbers of people, but sending out an announcement is perfectly appropriate if you restrict it to people who would genuinely like to hear about the paper for mathematical reasons, and not just as an advertisement for hiring you.

Comment: Maybe worth adding to your answer: in MathJobs, the reviewers for applications can both see the date an application was first submitted and the date where it last updated.  "Reapplying" will change the latter but not the former.  Also, at least in my experience, no one cares whether you submitted an application on time or not.  If the data is there when people want to see it, then that's good enough.  It's just that submitting late takes a big risk of the data not being there for people.

Comment: Thanks! this is very helpful. I will send announcements, but I know that at least some of these people are not reviewing applications (but of course they have a say on them...).

Comment: @MathMan I thought all faculty had a say in hiring postdocs; even though they might not be on the search committee, they can still pass along your name, and tell them that they are interested in you, which could put your name into the (longer) shortlist. Besides, announcing your results is something you should do anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I have had several of my pre-prints be submitted in the flurry of activity between job application and the last few months.  I haven't decided if it's still reasonable to re-submit or not . . .

I do know, or at least, this has been my own experience, that there is something funky going on in the mathjobs database on 'submission' dates and 'updated' dates.

I've had one application that I know that I had sent in by the deadline (I have an email from mathjobs indicating that all my material had been submitted) on such and such a date, but then when I highlight the little info image next to the job on the status page, it is several days afterwards.

I know that I did not un-apply for the position (as it was one of my top 5 post doc choices ), but I did do an update of the application, at some point (change some of the preprints to submitted).

I've only heard from two places so far (post-doc wise) on interviews.  I'm really not going to start sweating until a bit after the coordinated deadline, but it's not fun when it's all up in the air and you have no idea.

Actually, quick q and I'll probably run this by my advisor, but would it be appropriate to indicate the mathjobs fubar in the database to the school of interest?  I just don't want that to be the deciding factor for a position to be submission of materials on time or not, especially considering the mathjobs system is just plain wrong (and I can prove it)!

Comment: It's probably okay.  I was a bit worried when I updated one of my applications and then the 'submitted' date appeared as that day's date (almost two weeks after the closing date).  But it seems I'm on the short-list for that job, so I guess it didn't cause a problem.